# Algolia - WordPress - instantsearch page how do I exclude post with certain ID

Tags: wordpress, algolia

On Algolia instantsearch page (WordPress plugin) how do I exclude post with certain ID?

This is the default instantsearch setup. How do I add filter to exclude post ID from the search?

```
            var search = instantsearch({
                appId: algolia.application_id,
                apiKey: algolia.search_api_key,
                indexName: algolia.indices.searchable_posts.name,
                urlSync: {
                    mapping: {'q': 's'},
                    trackedParameters: ['query']
                },
                searchParameters: {
                    facetingAfterDistinct: true,
        highlightPreTag: '__ais-highlight__',
        highlightPostTag: '__/ais-highlight__'
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good solution to not display posts as part of the results is to not index them.

Indexing with the Algolia plugin for WordPress is explained here in detail: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/indexing-flow.html#indexing-decision

Here is a code snippet that should get you started:

```
<?php
// to put in the functions.php file of your active theme.
/**
 * @param bool    $should_index
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function exclude_post_ids( $should_index, WP_Post $post )
{
    // Add all post IDs you don't want to make searchable.
    $excluded_ids = array( 14, 66 );
    if ( false === $should_index ) {
        return false;
    }

    return ! in_array( $post->ID, $excluded_ids, true );
}

// Hook into Algolia to manipulate the post that should be indexed.
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'exclude_post_ids', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to plug in folder > includes > *class-algolia-search.php*

and find this code

```
$query->set( 'post__in', $post_ids );
```

exactly after that code add this code

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', array(1,2,3));
```

Then let me know the result.
In my code 1,2,3 are post ids which you want to exclude.
Thanks